# php yii framework, changing host in connect.php file cause website to hang?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Hope everything is fine.

I have a yii application, there is a connect.php file that will allow me to connect to the database.

```
$host= 'localhost';
$conresult= @mysql_connect($host, $mainuser, $pass);
//echo $db;
$result = mysql_select_db($db, $conresult);
if(!$result){
//echo "no";
}
```

We have moved the database server to the internal network for security reasons.

When I change the host from localhost to the new IP address, the website hangs.

The port is open and the security network saying that the connection is established.

How can I remotely connect to mysql server database in yii.

Thanks.

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated/removed `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` insteat

Comment: First of all, why do you still use `mysql_connect()`? It's deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7.0.  Second - why do you have file like this in **Yii Framework** - there's out of box DB connection, which will tell you why your connection is broken. [Yii Database DAO](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/pl/database.dao)

Comment: @Jens sorry my bad I am new to php

Comment: @Jens this is not my code, I am new to the project and it was developed by outsource company, I appreciate any help I am a .net person.

Comment: You should start from removing `@` from method call to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @rob006 I did  and I echo the conresult , and result  nothing happened.